# Generate documentation comments for typescript in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

When working in C# using ReSharper + StyleCop I can auto generate basic documentation comments for methods, which looks something like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The login.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="returnUrl">
    /// The return Url.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Task"/>.
    /// </returns>
```

which I can then add extra detail into.

Is there a similar tool for TypeScipt which will generate the JSDoc comment sections so I can simply fill in the details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReSharper has a backlog item for this - [Automated JavaScript Comments](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-213530).

At the moment, you just have to type `/**` and then enter them yourself.

There are some extension that [create vsdoc and jsdoc comments](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cb7304b-ad78-4283-ba2b-42804657fcdd)*.

*JSDoc added in v2.

Comment: Interesting and I wonder how long would it take MSFT to do this? 5 minutes?

Comment: The vsdoc extension mentioned in this answer has been updated to support both JSDoc and TypeScript!

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice little extension in the VS Code MarketPlace called **Document This**. Try that.
Other options are : Comments in **Typescript by S.Albert** and **DocStubsJs
by Michael Obermeyer**